# Building a form by combining other forms (like mailing address)

Tags: django, django-allauth

So I have an app that needs to store a lot of addresses in different forms.  I built an Address model (street,city,zip,state, etc).  So instead of having to repeat these in every model that needs and address, I'll just add an FK --> Address.

I also made a ModelForm out of the Address Model.

Is there anyway to do something like this?

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

  name = forms.CharField()
  phone = forms.CharField()
  address = [Fields from my Address ModelForm]
```

I can't use formsets because I'm doing this in a class for a specific module (all-auth).  All I can do is declare form fields and define the "signup" function.  All-Auth is doing the rest.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam')

    [Need to declare my address form here]

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django is Python, so you can have one Form `inherit` from another Form.  Like so:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['street', 'city', 'zip']

class ContactForm(AddressForm):
    # inherits fields from Addressform
    name = forms.CharField()
```